# int64 vs array(int64, 0d, C) in numba

Tags: python, numba

I define a jited function returning a tuple using numba. It's something like below.

```
import numba as nb
from numba.types import Tuple
import numpy as np

FOO_T = Tuple.from_types((nb.types.NPDatetime('M'), nb.int64))

@nb.jit([FOO_T(nb.types.NPDatetime('M'), nb.types.NPDatetime('M'))], nopython=True)
def foo(input1, input2):
    temp1 = input1
    temp2 = np.array(input1 - input2).view(nb.int64)
    
    output = (temp1, temp2)
    
    return output
```

A TypeError is reported as below. The second element of output tuple is defined as `int64`. However, it's actually compiled as `array(int64, 0d, C)`.

```
TypingError: No conversion from Tuple(datetime64[M], array(int64, 0d, C)) to Tuple(datetime64[M], int64) for '$38return_value.15', defined at None
```

Have no idea  how to make them consistent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: New to this area. I find one way to fix is converting 0d array to scalar using item(). temp2 = np.array(input1 - input2).view(nb.int64).item() can make it work, at least for now. Another question is how to define a 0d array in FOO_T, replacing nb.int64. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.array(input1 - input2).view(nb.int64)` is an array of `int64` and not a scalar. This is why Numba report an error. Note that `np.array(input1 - input2)` results in a weird type: an array of dimension 0. AFAIK, this is what Numpy use to represent scalars but such an array cannot be indexed in Numba nor converted to a scalar.

You could subtract two scalar and build an array with `np.array([input1 - input2])` and then call `view`. That being said, `view` is probably not what you want to do here as it reinterpret the binary representation of a `NPDatetime` as an integer. This is really unsafe and AFAIK there is no reason to assume that this can work. You can just make the difference and cast the result with `(np.uint64)(input1 - input2)`.